# Parse text as-is in knitr for rmarkdown to docx?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is there a way to parse text as is in rmarkdown, like the `<pre>` tag for HTML but for docx (Microsoft Word) export with `knitr`? When I use the tag `<pre>` it hides it in words... I could use a R code chunk and commenting it out but maybe there is a better way...

I would like to copy the output from R and paste it in my text markdown so it is always there...

For example

```
[1] “Results”  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

gives the following in Word after knitr export:

[1] “Noeuds”
2 3 4 5 6 7

I would like to keep the same formatting as the example..

This is what I use at the moment with an R code chunk:

````
```{r}
#[1] “Results”  
#    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```
````

Comment: are you looking for `asis=TRUE` in the chunk options? https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results (your question isn't entirely clear)

Comment: not really, I run the code in R, I copy paste the result in my rmarkdown file as normal text (without chunk) , but I want to keep the initial formating. Hope that is clearer..:/

Comment: but why are you copy and pasting? Can you please post a screenshot (not usually a good idea, but useful in this case) showing the formatting output you want in the final docx file? (I know you don't know how to generate it automatically, but you should be able to do the formatting by hand in Word to illustrate what you want ...)

Comment: I think there's a better solution, but in markdown triple-backtick (<code>```</code>: probably won't render right in a comment) denotes a generic code chunk (knitr won't try to execute it)

Comment: I appreciate the time you put in thinking about it :) I wanted to have the text as under "For example" but without the grey box. The triple tick works but leaves a grey box. But that's close enough for me :P thks !

Comment: you *might* be able to fix this by changing/modifying the highlighting style, but that's a little too much of a rabbit hole for me to go down right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either indent the text block by four spaces, or put it in a fenced code block, e.g.,

````
```
[1] “Results”  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```
````

[See](https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/thanks-tj-mahr/) Pandoc's documentation on [verbatim (code) blocks](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#verbatim-code-blocks).

Comment: thank you, @Ben Bolker answered in the comments, now with your answer it is crytal clear. If there is a solution without the grey box even better. Maybe I'll find it hidden somewhere in that doc. But that works for me. I'll accept the answer but credits to Ben ;P

Comment: You can disable syntax highlighting to remove the grey box. See `?rmarkdown::word_document` (set `highlight` to `null` in YAML under `word_document`).